# Algorithm to find if a number is sum of multiples of other numbers

Tags: algorithm, numbers

I have three numbers 6,9,20. For a given number I need to check if it can be equal to the sum of multiples of these three numbers.
For Ex:
n = 47 then it can be determined that 47 = 9*3 + 20

n=23 then there cannot be no combinations.

It can be determined in o(n^3). But is there a better way to do it ?

Comment: can the coefficients be negative?

Comment: you need to look at group theory and generators. It has been solved by mathematicians in order to determine for example the minimum set of coins (pennies,dollars) needed to cover the whole set of money values.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: n=41 could be solved with negative coefficients, so I guess not.

Comment: You're right, gcd is 1, so there's a solution for every number.

Comment: I think I misunderstand it, but 41= 2*6 + 1*9 + 1*20

Comment: 41 is a wrong example that i took .. correcting it

Answer (score 8):

This is a Linear Diophantine Equation.

If the coefficient can be negative, then check [Bézout's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity):

If the sum is a multiple of the gcd of the numbers, then there's a solution.

In your example gcd=1, so there's a solution for any sum. So I guess you're looking for non-negative coefficents.. :(

Comment: Károly, as an algorithm pro, could You take a look at my solution?

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution for You(only if coefficients can be 0).

Sum of multiples of 6 and 9 are all the multiples of 3 (except the 3 itself). So We can say, we need to check if a number equals to `3*k + 20*l`.

So, if You've got a number `n`,

- if `n` is multiple of 3, there is a decomposition and we can find it simple(if `n` is even, it is `x*6` , if it is odd, it is `9+x*6`
- if `n` is not a multiple of 3, decrease by 20 until it will be, than go to the first step.
  If You go below 0 and still didn't find a multiple of 3, there's no solution.
- there is at least one solution for every `n > 60`

Be careful with 23 and 43, since 3 can not be written that way, 23 and 43 can neither.

Why should this work? Because `20 mod 3 = 2`, `40 mod 3 = 1` , `60 mod 3 =0`. So after decreasing by 20 at most 2 times, You will find a multiple of 3 that can be solved easily.